# TinyMCE4 - Dynamic textareas stop working

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a script, where I dynamically add textareas (which should be tinymce4 fields) to a `ul`-List. There is also a possibility to rearange these list-rows by moving the textareas up and down.

My problem is, that after moving the textareas, they stop working. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/cagq503L/4/

Answer (score 0):

Before you move a `<texarea>` with TinyMCE you have to `remove()` TinyMCE from the `<texarea>` and then when the move is done you can once again `init()` the `<texarea>`.

This has to do with how the browser handles the iFrame that TinyMCE injects into the DOM and what happens if you rearrange the DOM after TinyMCE and its iFrame are initialized.